# Should I always inherit from Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract?

Tags: module, magento-1, helper

I heard conflicts opinions about weather or not one should only inherit from `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`, even when none of the helper built-ins are used.

So if I have couple of helper classes that I get using the magento `Mage::helper()` api, but those helpers don't use anything from `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`, should I still inherit from it?

My tendency goes with yes for good practice, but maybe there are performance / resources waste involved that I'm not aware of.

Thoughts?

EDIT: I saw examples in Magento code of helpers that inherit from helper abstract without using its functions (http://freegento.com/doc/d3/d82/_helper_2_string_8php-source.html). So unless someone gives me a good reason why I shouldn't do it, I think I'll go with "always inherit from helper abstract".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Magento relies on the `data` helper in a module for a lot of 'automatic' translation stuff like the labels in the `system.xml` for example.

This translation functionality is only available after extending `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`.

So I'd say it's not required but it's a good practice to do so and prevents issues in the future when you do rely on translations in your module

Comment: I think so too but I heard an experienced magento dev saying not to needlessly inherit from it (unfortunately without explaining why) and it made me wonder. You reinforced my natural tendency so I'll go with your way. Just to be clear though - I'm not talking about the default data helper, I'm talking about customized random helpers I create for my modules. If that somehow change your answer let me know :)

Comment: For other helpers beside the data helper I don't see any reason to inherit from the abstract helper

Comment: but do you see a reason not to? that's the question.. :)

Comment: Yes, that it's unnecessary. Why would you want to add code that you don't use? And a practical reason: IDE autocompletion. You only want to see the relevant methods there.

Comment: hm I think I agree with @fschmengler here. Except for data you probably don't want to extends the abstract class. Unless there is an explicit reason to do so